# How to add navigation menu in a custom landing page

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages, landing-pages

I am trying to create a Landing Page for my Magento site. I created this by creating a new CMS page through Admin/Content/Pages. I'm wondering if I can add a custom sticky navigation menu to this page? This custom sticky navigation will be different and in addition to my default website header.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to define a file in frontend/layout with name "default.xml" which actually lets you add custom things in headers/footers. See the code below: In component you give your JS file(if you want one for making it sticky) while in template you'll use html to show whatever you want in the header. P.S: See the difference between "templates" and "template" folder.Both are different. Hope it helps!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <head>
         <css src="Vendor_Module::css/vendor.cssfilename.css"/>
    </head>
     <body>
       <referenceContainer name="header.container">
           <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\File" name="name" template="Vendor_Module::"path_to_frontend_templateS"/file.phtml">
               <arguments>
                   <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="vendor-module-name" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/js_file</item>
                               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                   <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/"path_to_frontend_templatE"/html_file</item>
                               </item>
                           </item>
                       </item>
                   </argument>
               </arguments>
           </block>
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```